# Macro not responding on different computer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which works fine on my computer when I click its button but it does not work on different computers.
All the macros on that excel file are not working when clicking on the button.

However, I have a macro working before saving. That means that when I try to save, another macro works properly. (that macro pop up an input message, but is not relevant now). So it seems that macros are not working only when you call them by a click...

The version of Excel is the same one and I enabled the macro when asked.

It is not a problem of the code because even if I create a new simple macro on that file from the different PC (such as:

```
msgbox("hello")
```

) it is still not responding.

I had a problem with that excel file in the past and I had to manually delete all the *.exd extensions in my computer. However once I deleted those extensions, the file worked well.

I believe that the excel file is considered corrupted by other computers and they do not enable the macro. This is just my impression but I cannot get why the macro is working when saving and not working when clicking.

Do you have any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Read https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8f0af82-0bb8-4799-aa62-1dbcbc5b7742/excel-2010-macros-does-not-work-after-updates-9dec2014?forum=excel especially the last post from Hans Vogelaar. This means: All users which computers have installed the update in December 2014, that changed the behavior of ActiveX controls, have to delete the *.exd files from their user profiles. You have already done so, but the user on the other computer has not.

Comment: I let him do it as well, but it was still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues like that myself both with macros and with Excel workbook doing some really funny stuff (like formulas not calculating properly, or functions not working as expected etc) and I did not find any other solution then copying the content of the file and pasting into a newly created file.
In each case this resolved my problem.
It suggests that my files somehow got corrupted and the only solution was to save the contents and delete the files.
Exporting the .frm and .frx files from VBEditor (Modules and Forms) worked fine for me.
Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Yes I think this is the only solution. Unfortunately my file is very large and will take 6-8 hours to do so

Comment: If it comes to copy contents of your workbook, you could try running a simple macro - stored in the newly created Excel file - to import data from the corrupted file to that new file. I've never tried that myself (did not need that), but it could save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simple a suggestion, but have you checked the security settings in Excel?  The other computers may be set to a higher security setting that disables all macros without notifying the user.

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12?ui=en-US